# ActiveRecord.tt and Struct.tt causing compile errors

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic-active-record

I'm trying to update my ActiveRecord.cs and Struct.cs for a project after adding a column to a table on my database.  I've done this numerous times before, right click the tool and click 'Run Customer tool', and never had issues.

However this time I get a ton of errors (83 to be exact) after the tools finish running.  I've tried reverting the changes and running it again, but the errors still show up.  I really have no idea where to go from here since this has never happened before.  Is there something obvious I should check that could cause these tools to run incorrectly?

I'll provide a screenshot of some of the errors.
[image]

EDIT: Changed the screenshot to something easier to read.

Comment: Could be something like a missing brace in your template file. What do you see if you do a compare with structs.tt from github? Does it work if you use the fresh github templates?

Comment: I'll compare them.  I would find it really odd if one of those files was missing something.  Looking over the commits for this project I can't find any recent changes to the .tt files.

Comment: Another random idea, Just yesterday i had a plugin change my webconfig so a dll had assembly redirection to a different version. Caused some funny things to happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was that the .cs files were not being generated correctly.  This was caused by the db server we use timing out while the tools were running.  Reason I didn't catch it was because the timed out error wasn't listed the first couple times I tried this.